# React App - Include /health - Health Endpoint for Load Balancer

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React Application and I wish to deploy this behind a load balancer, where the load balancer periodically pings the app to see whether it's healthy. My requirement is to provide a `/health` endpoint, that can be used for health checking.

What would be the ideal way to implement a health endpoint?

- This is something that is required for anyone planning to deploy a React App in a auto-healing fashion
- The main page of this App is `/dashboard`, which is a heavy page. Hence, it cannot be used as a health endpoint.

i.e: I have seen react apps which have `/hello` kind of endpoints which return a simple message like `I am healthy`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will be answering my own question. After some considerable amount of research and asking around from experienced React developers, the following is the used approach for Including a health endpoint in React Applications.

This requirement came up when containerising the React App to be used in a Kubernetes Environment.

Do NOT ever try to use an existing page as your health check endpoint. Because, your regular pages are heavy and healthcheck endpoints need to be simple.

Hence, create a new route with `/health` (or a preferable path) and return a simple HTML element. given below is a Simple `Route` component.

```
<Route path="/health">
    <h3>Hey There!!! The App is Healthy</h3>
</Route>
```

This being used in a `Routes.js` file, is given below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>    
            {/* This endpoint will just return you to a dummy HTML with a simple heading tag */}
            <Route path="/health">
                <h3>Hey There!!! The App is Healthy</h3>
            </Route>

            {/* All other routes will be defined here */}

            {/* Finally you will be redirected to a not found page */}
            <Redirect to="/not-found" />
        </Switch>
    );
};

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Isn't the second answer makes more sense?
In your example you are still loading react library if code splitting done right otherwise a lot of not needed things will get bundled and downloaded.

Answer (score 15):

The answer above will work but the health endpoint will contain all of the index.html content which is technically unnecessary for the health endpoint.

A much better approach is just adding a file called `health` in the public folder. Then, when `/health` is called, the service will return the content of the file, which is faster and much smaller.